# Create a custom segmented date picker maui graphics

Tags: c#, uwp, maui

I want to create my own date picker control in the same vain as uwp for maui what I have so far is the following.

```
namespace MauiDatePicker.Drawable
{
    public class MauiDateTimmePickerDrawable : IDrawable
    {
        public Color StrokeColor { get; set; } = Colors.DarkGrey;

        public bool SetInvisible { get; set; } = false;

        public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
        {

            canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.DarkBlue;
            canvas.StrokeSize = 4;
            canvas.DrawRectangle(10, 10, 100, 50);

        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how one would create a 3 segment control that I could place the cursor in using maui graphics.

The code so far just draws a rectangle

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/datepicker ? (I believe not all of the Xamarin.Forms libraries have been moved to MAUI so these things are sometimes hard to find)

Comment: U cant just convert xamrain forms stuff maui .graphics changed how controls render

Comment: And no look at uwp it looks nothing like that one

Comment: Actually a good amount of Xamarin can be converted over to MAUI since MAUI was built essentially on top of Xamarin. You would have to mostly change namespaces and some small code changes, but if the concept exists in Xamarin it is most likely replicated in MAUI. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/migrate

But if you insist, you should probably remove the Xamarin tag from your question.

Comment: It appears you'll have to create a custom control if you want the scrolling feature. See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a538b5ae-85fc-45fe-b7a4-7098f23de8c6/duration-picker?forum=xamarinforms

Comment: Perhaps you could try building a custom control with multiple `Picker` next to each other. One for Month, Day, Year, in a single control: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker